# How can I Cover the gap in a Table using AUTO_INCREMENT field?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I cover the gap in a table column `product_id` which is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Should i drop the table ?

Its related to others tables with join.

Comment: Why do you think it matters?

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't. You have no problem at all. Even though my comment isn't what you want to read - it's 100% not related to any other table or join. If it is, you made a huge mistake and you're using the database wrong and you can ditch it and use a text file instead. There are no gaps, auto_increment doesn't produce "pretty" sequential numbers. It produces **unique** numbers. That means there's no correlation between a rows, they just get a unique number which is why you don't fix this problem. If you use a solution that "fixes" it - remember that it will break your database.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is not possible to cover the gap. You have to drop and recreate the table.

A second alternative is to manually create the elements in the gap expliciting manually the id value.

But it is not important if there is a gap. What is important is that id is unique. So don't mind about gap between values that comes if you delete some record.